# What's the best practice for connecting a table to multiple other tables where each has a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a rails blog, with a PostgreSQL database, where I have a `Post` model and `PodcastNote` model. I want to add a 'Tag' model, where `tags` can be for both `posts` and `podcast_notes`. In both cases, it will be a many-to-many relationship. My question is what is the best practice for handling that?

I can think of 2 ways:

1. Have 1 join model that connects `tags` to both `posts` and `podcast_notes`.
2. Have 2 join models - one that connects `tags` to `posts` and another that connects `tags` to `podcast_notes`

Which would be considered the best practice in this case?

If best practice is option 1 above, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You could do a polymorphic relationship on the Tag model. `belongs_to :target, polymorphic: true` and in each of the post and podcastnote, `has_many :post_tags, as: :target`. You may have to add something like source_type or something for the relationship to work

Answer (score 3):

One join model with a polymorphic association is the way most tagging gems solve this.

https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

https://github.com/pat/gutentag

Comment: I would recommend `ActsAsTaggableOn` too. Does what it is supposed to and well